# tikzpicture has a node whose text is a tree: unevenly formatting

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, trees

I want to typeset a picture similar to the following one, using tikz.

[image]

For that purpose I have written the following latex document

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  level distance=10mm,
  op/.style={circle,draw,fill=red!20},
  leaf/.style={circle,fill=blue!20,font=\ttfamily},
  ]
  \node (in) [fill=green!10] {\texttt{1 + 2*3}};
  \node (out) [fill=green!10,right=30mm of in] {
    \tikz{
      \node [op] {$+$}
        child { node [leaf] {1} }
        child { node [op] {$\times$}
          child { node [leaf] {2} }
          child { node [leaf] {3} }};
    }
  };
  \draw[->] (in) -- node [above] {\emph{parsing}} (out);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which gives me the output

[image]

Notice that in the tree, the left and right edges from each node are not symmetric: the left one is shorter than the right one. When the same tree is drawn outside of the `out` node, they are symmetric.

Why am I getting this effect, and how to fix this issue?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say it backwards:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  level distance=10mm,
  op/.style={circle,draw,fill=red!20},
  leaf/.style={circle,fill=blue!20,font=\ttfamily},
  ]
  \node (out) [fill=green!10] {
    \tikz{
      \node [op] {$+$}
        child { node [leaf] {1} }
        child { node [op] {$\times$}
          child { node [leaf] {2} }
          child { node [leaf] {3} }};
    }
  };
  \node (in) [fill=green!10,left=30mm of out] {\texttt{1 + 2*3}};
  \draw[->] (in) -- node [above] {\emph{parsing}} (out);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I really don't know why it works.

Comment: Yep, seems that the `right=of something` interferes with the layout of the tree nodes. I'd also really like to know why?

Comment: In fact the `right=of something` option enabled by the chains library seems to be the problem. Using `node distance=50mm,right of=in` instead of `right=30mm of in` in the `out` node gives a correct layout for the tree.